IntegrityError: insert or update on table
enter image description hereI am currently working on a web application that uses Django as a backend, Django Rest Framework as an API, React as a frontend, and PostgreSQL as a database. For user authentication, I utilized SimpleJWT. However, I encountered an issue where I am able to create a user account through the frontend, but I cannot log in with the newly created account. There's an error message appearing in the console, the user information is present in the database. However, I can still log in with a couple of accounts that were created a while ago(all accounts from the same database table), both through the front end and Django Rest Framework.
I keep getting this error on Django:
the parenthesis for (user_id) can be different every time in the error
IntegrityError at /api/token/

insert or update on table "token_blacklist_outstandingtoken" violates foreign key constraint "token_blacklist_outs_user_id_83bc629a_fk_auth_user"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(4) is not present in table "auth_user".

Here's my database table, this first 3 accounts I can successfully log in through frontend and Rest framework
settings.py (only the simpleJWT part):
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=30),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=90),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": True,
    # FOR SECURITY REASON (ABOVE)
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}

api/models.py
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser  
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):     
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)     
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)      
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'     
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

api/serializers.py
from api.models import CustomUser
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['email'] = user.email
        return token


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    confirmed_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'confirmed_password')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['confirmed_password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "Password fields didn't match."})
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

api/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import MyTokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import(
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes),

    path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='auth_register'),
]

api/views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import generics
from api.models import CustomUser
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .serializers import MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, RegisterSerializer

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
    '/api/token',
    '/api/register',
    '/api/token/refresh'
    ]
    return Response(routes)


What's your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting set to?

in my settings.py AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.CustomUser'

You're saving your accounts to a new custom model CusomUser although the token is checking with the built in auth_user model hence the error DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(4) is not present in table "auth_user"., try to open the auth_user table and you'll most likely find only the 3 accounts you were able to login with, so either use the auth_user model as your main model for users and start saving to that model or change the token settings to check with the CustomUser model.

I have 3 accounts from auth_user table, but I cannot login with those account. I can login with first 3 account from api_customeuser table. Is there any way I can fix the issues? I have been stuck on this issue for more than a week :(
Please help.

Here are the screenshot from pgAdmin:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Coj7iEqIJ2b-azGfVPUeat17cXzOhD0/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hndjsF1F1dsgzJORfuku2VIA7I56WLuV/view?usp=sharing
